# Is there way to compile ffmpeg in VS 2019 without (1) installing MSYS, (2) using assembler sources?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to compile `ffmpeg` in VS 2019 without installing additional components such as `MSYS` and assembler sources.
If I understand correctly, I have to install MSYS to do that and I would like not install it.

Can I do it without `MSYS` - and if it is real, in what way ?
I have downloaded `ffmpeg` sources and the first step to install it - execute a file `.\configure` (bash script?) that comes with `ffmpeg`.

Comment: You could use vcpkg to build: [https://gist.github.com/genbtc/ffbcd1c6e2a02b03e9a86e82d3d54f21](https://gist.github.com/genbtc/ffbcd1c6e2a02b03e9a86e82d3d54f21)

Comment: Though Vcpkg sometimes installs MSYS2 internally to build some packages, wouldn't be surprised if they do it for ffmpeg too.

Comment: see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC